# Spark Structured streaming getting incorrect number of input rows when using StreamingQueryListener QueryProgressEvent

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am facing issue in using StreamingQueryListener to identify number of input row, I am using

`queryProgress.progress().numInputRows()`

I get proper count when there is no other action apart from write, but the moment I add certain actions such as df.count or df.isEmpty() my number of input rows count get disrupted.

Any help is highly appreciated

EDIT

**Below code works**

```java
df.writeStream().outputMode("append").foreachBatch(new VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>,Long>(){
  @Override
  public void call(Dataset<Row> streamDataset, Long batchId) throws Exception {
    streamDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).save("namesAndFavColors.parquet");
  }
}).start();
```

This gives wrong count

```java
df.writeStream().outputMode("append").foreachBatch(new VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>,Long>(){
  @Override
  public void call(Dataset<Row> streamDataset, Long batchId) throws Exception {
    streamDataset.count();                                    
    streamDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).save("namesAndFavColors.parquet");
  }
}).start();
```

**Note**

Please ignore write() code, in real scenario data is being written to mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining more than just one action as in

```
streamDataset.count();                                    
streamDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).save("namesAndFavColors.parquet");
```

Spark creates two "seperate" streams that each consume same data. However, both streams are calling the `onQueryProgress`. This happens at the same time as those two streams are wrapped into the same `foreachBatch`.

In your particular case you will therefore see twice as much data in your `NumInputRows` compared to the output of `count`.

The factor will increase depending on the amount of actions you have.

Comment: Thanks mike, but what could be a solution for this

Comment: You can divide the output from `query.progess.NumInputRows` by the number of actions/streams within your SparkSession.